# Defining a method for bigdecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to define my own method for BigDecimal.
The method takes two BigDecimal as parameter and do something with them.

```java
private boolean doSomething(BigDecimal left, BigDecimal right){
    do something...
}
```

And I call it by

```java
doSomething(b1, b2);
```

But I think it should be handled by BigDecimal object,
Is there any way to define it in BigDecimal class and call it like this?

```java
b1.doSomething(b2);
```

Comment: *But I think it should be handled by BigDecimal object* - why? Can you be more concrete?

Comment: No, you cannot add methods to classes that are now your own.

Comment: I believe the only way to do that is to create a new class that extends BigDecimal then add the new method in that class instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can extends the class BigDecimal, then create your own function. It goes something like this. Hope this helps.

```
public class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CustomBigDecimal d1 = new CustomBigDecimal(100);
        d1.somefunction();
    }
}

class CustomBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {
    public CustomBigDecimal(int val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public void somefunction(){
    }
}
```